# IllegalArgumentException when formatting a Java MessageFormat text

Tags: java, illegalargumentexception

I'm given the main and the TEXT but all of the other classes and implementation are possible to be the cause of the error.

**Updated**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;


class BankAccount extends AccountHolder { 
private static final String TEXT =  "I am a {0} account with {1} units of {2} 
currency";

public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {

    List<BankAccount> accounts = new ArrayList<BankAccount>();
    accounts.add(new SavingsAccount("USD",3));//Savings
    accounts.add(new SavingsAccount("EUR",2));//Savings
    accounts.add(new CheckingAccount("HUF",100));//Checking
    accounts.add(new CheckingAccount("COP",10000));//Checking
    accounts.add(new BrokerageAccount("GBP",2));//Brokerage
    accounts.add(new BrokerageAccount("INR",600));//Brokerage

    accounts.stream().forEach(
                                account -> System.out.println(
                                    MessageFormat.format(TEXT,
                                        new Object[]{

account.getAccountType().getName(),//make this work
                                        account.getUnits(),//make this work
                                        account.getCurrency()//make this work
                                                       })));
}

AccountHolder customer = new AccountHolder();
String units;
Integer currency;

void setCustomer(AccountHolder acctHolder) {
    this.customer = acctHolder;
}

AccountHolder getAccountType() {
    return customer;
}

//set units
void setUnits(String unit) {
    this.units = unit;
}

void setType(String type) {
    customer.setType(type);
}

String getUnits() {
    return units;
}

//set currency 
void setCurrency(Integer curr) {
    this.currency = curr;       
 }

Integer getCurrency() {
    return currency;
  }
 }

class SavingsAccount extends BankAccount {

SavingsAccount(String unit, Integer curr) {
    super.setName("Saving");
    super.setUnits(unit);
    super.setCurrency(curr);
  } 
 }

class CheckingAccount extends BankAccount {

CheckingAccount(String unit, Integer curr) {
    super.setName("Checking");
    super.setUnits(unit);
    super.setCurrency(curr);
  } 
 }

 class BrokerageAccount extends BankAccount {

 BrokerageAccount(String unit, Integer curr) {
    super.setName("Brokerage");
    super.setUnits(unit);
    super.setCurrency(curr);
}   
}

 class AccountHolder {

 String name;
 String acctType;

String getName() {
    return name;
}   

void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

void setType(String type) {
    this.acctType = type;
}

String getType() {
    return acctType;
  }
 }
```

**Updated Revised**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;


class BankAccount extends AccountHolder { 
private static final String TEXT =  "I am a {0} account with {1,number,#} 
units of {2} currency";

public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {

    List<BankAccount> accounts = new ArrayList<BankAccount>();
    accounts.add(new SavingsAccount("USD",3));//Savings
    accounts.add(new SavingsAccount("EUR",2));//Savings
    accounts.add(new CheckingAccount("HUF",100));//Checking
    accounts.add(new CheckingAccount("COP",10000));//Checking
    accounts.add(new BrokerageAccount("GBP",2));//Brokerage
    accounts.add(new BrokerageAccount("INR",600));//Brokerage

    accounts.stream().forEach(
                                account -> System.out.println(
                                    MessageFormat.format(TEXT,
                                        new Object[]{

account.getAccountType().getName(),//make this work
                                        account.getUnits(),//make this work
                                        account.getCurrency()//make this work
                                                       })));
}

AccountHolder customer = new AccountHolder();
Integer units;
String currency;

void setCustomer(AccountHolder acctHolder) {
    this.customer = acctHolder;
}

AccountHolder getAccountType() {
    return customer;
}

//set units
void setUnits(Integer unit) {
    this.units = unit;
}

void setType(String type) {
    customer.setType(type);
}

Integer getUnits() {
    return units;
}

//set currency 
void setCurrency(String curr) {
    this.currency = curr;       
}

String getCurrency() {
    return currency;
 }
}

class SavingsAccount extends BankAccount {

 SavingsAccount(String curr, Integer unit) {
    super.getAccountType().setName("Saving");
    super.setUnits(unit);
    super.setCurrency(curr);
  } 
 }

class CheckingAccount extends BankAccount {

 CheckingAccount(String curr, Integer unit) {
    super.setUnits(unit);
    super.getAccountType().setName("Checking");
    super.setCurrency(curr);
 }  
}

class BrokerageAccount extends BankAccount {

BrokerageAccount(String curr, Integer unit) {
    super.getAccountType().setName("Brokerage");
    super.setUnits(unit);
    super.setCurrency(curr);
    }   
 }

class AccountHolder {

 String name;
 String acctType;

 String getName() {
    return name;
 }   

 void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
 }

 void setType(String type) {
    this.acctType = type;
 }

 String getType() {
    return acctType;
 }
}
```

This is that the console stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Number
    at java.text.DecimalFormat.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.Format.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.MessageFormat.subformat(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.MessageFormat.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.Format.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.MessageFormat.format(Unknown Source)
    at BankAccount.lambda$main$0(BankAccount.java:22)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(Unknown Source)
    at BankAccount.main(BankAccount.java:20)
```

I've tried returning the currency as an Integer as shown but also Number, and casting but all return an error somewhat similar.  The use of Strings doesn't have issue it's only with the creation of the new Objects and passing through with the numeric value.  It's provided the type is of Object.

**Edit**
I changed the units into Number type from the input given. Now I get

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input 
 string: 
   "USD"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Unknown Source)
    at SavingsAccount.<init>(BankAccount.java:69)
    at BankAccount.main(BankAccount.java:13)
```

Comment: `account.getUnits()` returns a **`String`**. Why do you believe you can format a `String` as a number? The documentation of [`MessageFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) says it will use [`DecimalFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html), and it says: *The number can be of **any subclass of `Number`**.* `String` is not a subclass of `Number`.

Comment: @Andreas I added the changes I made.  It's throwing another error NumberFormatException.

Comment: Why is `unit` value `"USD"` if it's supposed to be a number? You seem to have flipped the values and/or types in multiple places in your code. Re-check all your code, and make sure you know what "unit" and "currency" is supposed to mean. I'd suggest renaming "unit" to "amount" to clarify the meaning, since "unit" is too close to "unit of measure" (e.g. a "mile", i.e. not a number).

Comment: @Andreas Thanks I got it working.  I think I was just being confused with the naming that was given as you too mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BankAccount.units` field is of type `String` however you are attempting to display it as a number with `{1,number,#}` format.

Either change `units` to something that can be converted to a numbers (e.g. `Integer`) or use a different format to print it (e.g. display as-is with just `{1}`).

Comment: Realistically, it seems like they probably swapped the order of the units/quantity parameters.

Comment: @VeeArr you might be right, however it's up to the author to decide.

Comment: @Karol You were right I was though it seems now I am not populating the name either.

Comment: @KarolDowbecki This was not a given author and no parameters were allowed to be changed as the variables were decided.  Automated code generators create wrong problems that aren't solvable all the time with type arguments the most common.

Answer (score 1):

Your format string is:

```
I am a {0} account with {1,number,#} units of {2} currency
```

and the `MessageFormat.format` call supplies the values:

```
new Object[] {
        account.getAccountType().getName(),
        account.getUnits(),    // <== String
        account.getCurrency()  // <== Integer
}
```

but it is unclear what `unit` and `currency` are supposed to represent, given that `unit` is a `String` and `currency` is an `Integer`.

It seems you have flipped the types of the two fields.

Comment: This was in response to a pre-composed problem which stated what I could and couldn't change.

Comment: @April_Nara If it is a pre-composed problem, i.e. the names and types were pre-defined, it seems you've confused the **meaning** of the values. E.g. is `20 USD` supposed to be `unit=20, currency="USD"` or `unit="USD", currency=20`? According to the types, it's the second, but your `MessageFormat.format` call passes the values as-if it's the first. Check your assumptions.

Answer (score -1):

Looking at the string format, units (1,20,100) should be an Integer and currency (USD, INR, GBP) a String. Rest of the code looks good.

Comment: Right though they are.